# onmouseover Causing Blinking

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using onmouseover, the z-index property, and a set of CSS classes to display text hidden behind an image.  However, my images blink rapidly when hovered over.  Can anybody help me out? (This is in a wordpress theme)

The problem is in this line, in the onmouseout... I just don't know how to modify it to fix the problem:

```
<span class="displayer" onmouseover="this.className='hidden'" onmouseout="this.className='displayer'">
```

My markup:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">
<div id="portfolio_content">

<!-- Grab posts -->
<div id="portfolio_wrap">
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  

<!-- Get the image -->
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">


<span class="img">

<span class="displayer" onmouseover="this.className='hidden'" onmouseout="this.className='displayer'">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'thmb-portfolio' ); } ?>
</span>


<!-- Excerpt title -->
<span class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>

<!-- Excerpt description -->
<span class="desc">
    <?php my_excerpt('short'); ?>
</span>
</span>
</a>


<?php endwhile; ?>

<!-- Next/Previous Posts -->
<?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {
    pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);
} ?>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

My CSS

```
#portfolio_content ul {
    list-style:none
}
#portfolio_content .img a {
    color:#444;
    z-index:110!important
}
#portfolio_content .img a:hover { }
#portfolio_content .img {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:250px;
    margin:0 35px 35px 0!important;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0;
    width:352px
}
#portfolio_content .img img {
    display:block;
    position:absolute!important;
    z-index:100!important
}
#portfolio_content .img img:hover {
    z-index:0!important
}
#portfolio_content .img .title, #portfolio_content .img .title a {
    font-size:22px;
    width:352px!important;
    height:250px!impotant;
    float:left!important;
    text-align:center;
    margin:100px 0 10px 0;
    position:relative!important;
    color:#444
}
.desc {
    font-size:13px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center!important;
    margin:0 auto!important;
    width:352px;
    color:#444
}
.displayer {
    display:block;
    background:#1a1a1a;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:352px;
    height:250px;
    z-index:900!important
}
.hidden { display:none }
```

Comment: are you using CSS sprites for your images?

Comment: No, the code and CSS provided are all I am using but it causes blinking.  I know this can be solved by modifying onmouseout on this line: <span class="displayer" onmouseover="this.className='hidden'" onmouseout="this.className='displayer'"> ... I just don't know how.

Comment: Can you add a link to your site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiding an element that has the mouse pointer over it causes onmouseout to fire, displaying the element again, which hides the element, etc etc.  You should probably attach your "re-show the div" event to something else, like a click for example.

Better example:  When you image div is hidden by mousing over, does another element take its place?  You mention a hidden text element behind it.  Try attaching the "Re-show div" handler to the onmouseout of the text div, while leaving the "hide div" handler where it is (attached to the onmouseover of the image div).

Comment: That really wouldn't help in this situation, since I need to do this on-over, not click.

Comment: OK, but that is why it's flashing :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using CSS sprites as most of the time a hover image flicker is caused by the time it takes for the browser to load the image when called by the hover. A sprite will load all of the images at once and eliminate the flicker.
[Css sprites](http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/)

Comment: There is only one image there, the words behind it are simply text.  CSS sprites does not apply.