# Why it will produce blinking effect when css turn from visibility visible to hidden

Tags: javascript, css

```
<div style='position:relative'>
<div id ='tag' style=' border: 1px solid red; position : absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; width: 50px; height: 50px;'></div>
<img src='http://localhost/jlin.jpg' id='wow'>
</div>
```

This is my html code

```
window.onload = function(){
    var tag = document.getElementById('tag');

    tag.onmouseover = function(){
      tag.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    tag.onmouseout = function(){
    tag.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

This is my javsacript code.
I want the inner div to hide when I mouse ober it and appear again when I put my  mouse cursor out of it.Why the div inside keep on blinking when I put my mouse on the inner div?

The second Question: Actually I want to create a tagging effect so when I mouse over the div it will appear. So I change my javascript code to this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var tag = document.getElementById('tag');
    tag.style.visibility = "hidden";
    tag.onmouseover = function(){
      tag.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    tag.onmouseout = function(){
    tag.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

It doesn't work. I tried another way which I add the `visibility: hidden;` inline inside  the innerDiv and set the javascript as following:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var tag = document.getElementById('tag');
    tag.onmouseover = function(){
      tag.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

It seems like it does not work too, why?
This is the fiddle for 1st question: http://jsfiddle.net/uFLPg/

Comment: Could please give us fiddle

Comment: updated, please check it out :)

Comment: Why not just use `#tag { visibility: hidden }` and `#tag:hover { visibility: visible }` ?

Comment: yea, i know this method, but some time i want to create more complicated application using javascript, why my code dont work?

Comment: You are going to need to use 'opacity' and not 'visibility'.

Comment: When the div is hidden, onmouseover ends and onmouseout begins, in an endless cycle that looks like blinking. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407767/onmouseover-causing-blinking

Answer (score 5):

When `visibility: hidden` is set, no mouse events are sent to the element.

What you were seeing is the `mouseout` event firing as the element went hidden which then caused the code to set it visible again which then triggered the `mouseover` event as soon as the mouse moved - and so on.

Some additional information here: [Does opacity:0 have exactly the same effect as visibility:hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272360/does-opacity0-have-exactly-the-same-effect-as-visibilityhidden)

Use `opacity: 0` instead.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/uFLPg/2/)

```
window.onload = function(){
    var tag = document.getElementById('tag');

    tag.style.opacity = 0;
    tag.onmouseover = function () {
        tag.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    tag.onmouseout = function () {
        tag.style.opacity = 0;
    }
}
```

---

If you are concerned about older browser support for opacity, you can still use `visibility: hidden;` by wrapping  the `tag` div in a `div` with its background set to `transparent`.

Attach the mouseover/mouseout handlers to the wrapping div and change the visibility of the child.  This avoids the repeated mouseover/mouseout events as the wrapper will always receive mouse events.

[Demo 2:](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/uFLPg/4/)

HTML:

```
<div style='position:relative'>
    <div id='tag' style='position : absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; width: 50px; height: 50px; z-index: 10; background: transparent;'>
        <div id='tagInner' style=' border: 1px solid red; position : absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;'>     
    </div>
    </div>
    <img src='http://www.hihowareyou.com/store/images/products/tn_HiVinylFrontmed.jpg' id='wow'>
</div>
```

Code:

```
var tag      = document.getElementById('tag');
var tagInner = document.getElementById('tagInner');

tagInner.style.visibility = 'hidden';
tag.onmouseover = function () {
    tagInner.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
tag.onmouseout = function () {
    tagInner.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

---

There is also an interesting writeup on CSSTricks about [CSS Transparency Settings for All Browsers](http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/).  I haven't tried that approach myself with older browsers, but it may work for you.

Comment: can you provide reference or documentation so I can know more about it :)??

Comment: @dramasea I can't seem to dig it out of the spec but did find several references on stack overflow.  Added a link to one in the answer.

Comment: @dramasea - added an approach that will work for `visibility: hidden` and a link to a CSSTricks article about backwards compatible transparency.

Comment: life saver.  :)(y)

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to accomplish can be done in CSS:

```
#tag:hover { opacity: 0; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rh5wb/

Comment: is it posible that i use js??

Comment: If this is the extent of your issue, js may be unnecessary. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

Using opacity and js

```
var tag = document.getElementById('tag');

tag.onmouseover = function () {
    tag.style.opacity = 0;
}
tag.onmouseout = function () {
    tag.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uFLPg/1/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/uFLPg/1/)